# Upload file into doument library and update the metadata using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, file-upload

How to upload the file into the document library and insert/update the metadata columns.I am having 3 people picker data types/user group columns and one choice field and 2  single line of text columns. I have written the PowerShell to upload the document in the  document library but how to get the item which is inserted and update the  metadata. Do I need to use the getitembyid()? Also when I ran the script it inserted successfully and its checked-out.

```
         [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName 
        ("Microsoft.SharePoint")
        if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -
        eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
            Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
              }

           #Site Collection where you want to upload files
          $siteCollUrl 
            = "http://srvr1:123/sites/R-Engineering/"
          #Document Library where you want to upload files
         $libraryName = "KG"
         #Physical/Network location of files
          $reportFilesLocation  = "E:\Maddy\Scripts\FileUpload"

        $spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteCollUrl;
        $spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$libraryName];

            if($spSourceList -eq $null)
            {
           Write-Host "The Library $libraryName could not be found."
            return;
            }

   $files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item 
    $reportFilesLocation)).GetFiles()
  foreach($file in $files)
  {
    #Open file
   $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()

   #Add file
   $folder =  $spSourceWeb.getfolder($libraryName)

   Write-Host "Copying file $file to $libraryName..."
   $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name,   
   [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)

   #Close file stream
  $fileStream.Close();
 }
$spSourceWeb.dispose();
Write-Host "Files have been uploaded to $libraryName."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right after you add the file:

```
$item = $spFile.Item;
$item["TextOrChoiceColumnInternalName"] = "New Value"
$spUser = Get-SPUser -Identity "domain\username" -Web $spSourceWeb;
$item["UserFieldInternalName"] = $spUser;
$item.SystemUpdate($false);
```

Use `SystemUpdate($false)` if you don't want to increase the version of the item..

To check in a file use:

```
$spFile.CheckIn("Checked In By Administrator")
```

To publish a file:

```
$spFile.Publish("Automatically published by Powershell")
```

To approve a file:

```
$spFile.Approve("Automatically approved by by Powershell");
```

Comment: Thanks. Its checked out now.How can I check in this item & publish through PowerShell.

Comment: Edited my answer.